# How do I switch user account in drush to test permissions?

Tags: drush, 9

I'm playing around with the D9 Groups module and I want to test the access control in drush, either using drush php or writing a script and using drush scr.

In drush 8 I would always use drush -u to run as a specific user but that option seems to have disappeared in drush 10.

What's the easiest way to either run drush as a specific user or switch the user in drush php or a script?

Edit: I'm working around this by making calls to json:api endpoints instead but it would still be nice to validate this in drush.

Comment: I know you're asking for Drush but it's worth noting that the Devel module provides a block for switching users, which can be useful in a local dev environment.

Comment: Yeah testing in browser is fine, but I specifically need to test at the cli or api level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi In your test you could use account switcher service @ `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/AccountSwitcherInterface.php`

For example,

```
// You can switch to any type of account here.
$this->accountSwitcher->switchTo(new UserSession(['uid' => 1]));

// Using try-catch-finally we make sure we be never leave it by accident.
try {
  // Whatever you want to test
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  $this->logger->get(self::MODULE_NAME)->error($e->getMessage());
} finally {
  // Making sure we always switch back. Very important if you using u1.
  $this->accountSwitcher->switchBack();
}
```